# How to call the variables from the config file in rclone copy command

Tags: environment-variables, config, rclone

I want to copy my files into s3 storage using rclone. Here is my config file:

```
[dt]
type = s3
provider = Other
endpoint = https://s3.xx.com
remote_directory = /work/data
access_key_id = XX
secret_access_key = 1233XXX
source_data_folder = /datasets/test/
```

How can I call remote_directory and source_data_folder from my config file (test.conf), instead of manually specifying their values in the command below:

```
rclone --config test.conf -P --transfers 10 copy /work/data dt:/datasets/test/
```